# XCeed grid delete from virtualized source

Tags: c#, xceed, xceed-datagrid

I'm taking a look at XCeed's WPF data grid samples trying to figure out how to delete a row when in "virtualized data" mode.

I don't understand how can a row be deleted since the underlying virtual collection does not implement any of the remove methods.

Any help on this would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

The DataGridCollectionViewBase class includes public events that let you capture when the user made changes to the grid (add/delete/modify). It is then up to you to actually push those changes to your database.

For example:

```
<xcdg:DataGridVirtualizingCollectionView x:Key="mySource" 
                                         ItemRemoved="VirtualizingCollectionView_ItemRemoved" />

private void VirtualizingCollectionView_ItemRemoved(object sender, DataGridItemRemovedEventArgs e)
{
    // your custom code here
}
```